# Split a string on the Empty Character literal. Break apart a string's symbols into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, explode

i have the following string =

```
"00101010"
```

and i need the following array/list:

```
var.ElementAt(0) = "0"
var.ElementAt(1) = "0"
var.ElementAt(2) = "1"
var.ElementAt(3) = "0"
var.ElementAt(4) = "1"
var.ElementAt(5) = "0"
var.ElementAt(6) = "1"
var.ElementAt(7) = "0"
```

if i try string.split('') the compiler complains about a empty character literal.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't match the original string.

Comment: Can't you just use str[index]?

Comment: why would i use str[i] when i want a array? i dont wanna loop. i want dynamics. not statics. wish i could down vote comments

Comment: as you see from the question i have tried string.split. nice try though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Linq:

```
var chars = "00101010".Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
string mys = "hello";
char[] thechars = mys.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: But only if OP would need a `Char[]` instead of a `String[]` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Use [ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx). But the more pertinent question is what you need to do with your result since string already implements `IEnumerable<char>` allowing you to iterate and do whatever you need with the characters in the string.

Comment: He wants string back, not char.

Comment: What he *wants* and what he *needs* are likely two *very* different things.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a specific character in a string, just index the string; there is no need to convert it to an array of anything:

```
var s = "0123";
var c = s[0]; // -> '0'
```

If you really need strings and not chars, then Tim's answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a one line reg-ex solution that returns string[] instead of char[]:

```
    var arr = Regex.Split(s, "(?<=.)(?=.)");
```

It'd be interesting if there's a one line non-Linq solution or a shorter correct reg-ex.

Note: I'd have posted under the other reg-ex answer but it seems to have been deleted due to missing @ string prefix and it's limitation to only splitting digits.